# URL Decoding in PHP

Tags: php, url, utf-8, urldecode

I am trying to decode this URL string using PHP's urldecode function:

```
urldecode("Ant%C3%B4nio+Carlos+Jobim");
```

This is supposed to output...

```
'Antônio Carlos Jobim'
```

...but instead is ouptutting this

```
'AntÃ´nio Carlos Jobim'
```

I've tested the string in a [JS-based online decoder](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) with great success, but can't seem to do this operation server side. Any ideas?

Comment: What method are you using to output it?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Your string is *also* UTF-8 encoded. This will work:

```
echo utf8_decode(urldecode("Ant%C3%B4nio+Carlos+Jobim"));
```

Output: "Antônio Carlos Jobim".

Comment: only if page declared `ISO-8859-1` encoding.

Answer (score 14):

Actually, you get the desired output, but it is not interpreted as UTF-8. If this is on an HTTP application, you should send a header or a meta tag (or both) which would tell the client to use UTF-8.

**Edit:** for example:

```
// replace text/html with the content type you're using
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

Answer (score 3):

when I do

```
<?php
echo urldecode("Ant%C3%B4nio+Carlos+Jobim");
?>
```

Its display correctly in my browser like

> Antônio Carlos Jobim

I have tested with XAMPP

Answer (score 3):

another option is:

```
<?php
$smthing = 'http%3A%2F%2Fmysite.com';
$smthing = preg_replace("/%u([0-9a-f]{3,4})/i","&#x\\1;",urldecode($smthing)); 
$smthing = html_entity_decode($smthing,null,'UTF-8');
echo $smthing;
?>
```

output becomes : `http://mysite.com`

Comment: This works. Only urldecode() won't decode whole URL with query params.
Problem is that your solution thinks too long :/

Answer (score 1):

Are you also using `htmlenteties` before echoing it to the page? When I just tested your code it worked fine with just the `urldecode("Ant%C3%B4nio+Carlos+Jobim");` part, but when I ran it through `htmlentities` I got the same output as you did.

It seems to be a problem with the UTF-8 characters and how PHP handles the `htmlentities` function.

Comment: It works correctly if you specify the right encoding as the `$charset` parameter. And anyway, you should be using `htmlspecialchars`, not `htmlentities`, if all you want to do is protect from XSS.