# "Unserialize" this string : %C3%A9%C3%A0%C3%A9%C3%A0

Tags: jquery, mysql, utf-8, serialization, decode

I have a really annoying problem:

I had a string **éàéà** which I passed in the [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) function.
It gave me the string **%C3%A9%C3%A0%C3%A9%C3%A0**.

How can I come back (either in JS or PHP) to **éàéà** to save the string properly in my MySQL UTF-8 encoded database?

thanks in advance,

Comment: How are you going to store data in a database from jQuery?

Comment: Probably with AJAX back to the server, or even in a local database, as supported by most of the latest browsers.

Answer (score 8):

It's been [URL-encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). You just need to [URL-decode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756862/url-decoding-in-php) it.

See also:

- [PHP URL decoding](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+url+decode)
- [JavaScript URL decoding](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+url+decode)

Answer (score 4):

Javascript's native `decodeURI` function or the related `decodeURIComponent` function should do it.  W3Schools has some example code for [`decodeURI`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuri.asp) and for [`decodeURIComponent`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuricomponent.asp).  If you're decoding only stuff generated by jQuery's `serialize` function, then the latter is probably more appropriate but if you are decoding an entire URI, then the former would be more appropriate.

Comment: ok, thanks, here is the PHP code which do the job:
utf8_decode(urldecode($v)),

Comment: Yeah, that PHP code for it is referenced in Matt Ball's answer so he deserves a +1!

Answer (score 2):

Looks URL encoded, to me.

In javascript:

```
decodeURIComponent("%C3%A9%C3%A0%C3%A9%C3%A0");
```