# how to pass variable in get without special char and retrieve back

Tags: php, mysql, post, get

how to pass variable in get without %20 %27 and retrieve back exactly what is passed i tried urlencode and decode but not works need some help

passing in url http://localhost/civilhelp/enquiry.php?cat=%27PLUMBING%20FITTINGS%20&%20SANITARY%20WARE%27
 i need to remove %27 %20 used urlencode but no use

retrive only PLUMBING FITTINGS and remaining pls anybody help with a solution

i am passing it as

```
 $cate = 'PLUMBING FITTINGS & SANITARY WARE'; it is from db
    <a href="enquiry.php?cat='<?php echo urlencode($cate)  ;?>'">
```

try to retrieve as

```
$category = urldecode($_GET['cat']); 
$category = str_replace("'"," ",$category);
print_r($category); 
$category = trim($category);
```

`print_r($category);` it just prints PLUMBING FITTINGS

Am not getting exactly aht i passed 
Note: I have used urlencode and urldecode  also trim

But still i can't Hope what is my problem!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [URL Decoding in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756862/url-decoding-in-php)

Comment: I have no idea what you're doing with your `urlencode`, but it should **not** produce that encoding: http://3v4l.org/EMqRj

Comment: remove the single quotes around your the `urlencode()` command

Comment: don't use urldecode it will be decoded automatically

Answer (score 0):

that cannot be right i tried your code and it show the correct data try this

```
$url = 'http://localhost/civilhelp/enquiry.php?cat=%27PLUMBING%20FITTINGS%20&%20SANITARY%20WARE%27';
$category = urldecode($url);
$category = str_replace("'","",$category);
echo $category; // result: http://localhost/civilhelp/enquiry.php?cat=PLUMBING FITTINGS & SANITARY WARE
```

EDIT:
i got your problem just in the cat='' change & to %26

Comment: yes but i just need  $cat = PLUMBING FITTINGS & SANITARY WARE and not url

Comment: when you redirect to the enquiry with cat query string instead of & change it to %26    

i think there should be someway that you redirect the user to enquiry.php?cat=     

if he clicked a button or something just in its value change & to %26

Comment: still i can't get you

Comment: from where you get that enquiry.php?cat= url redirection ?

Comment: Yes i understand my problem with & but don't know how to proceed i m stucked

Comment: as i asked from you get that enquiry.php?cat='' url redirection, what is the script that controls it ? index.php ??

Comment: Yes understand and  will post answer soon

Comment: Mohamed thanks a  lot finally it works by using  $cat = str_replace('&', '%26', $cat);

Comment: please if this answer was correct mark it as correct answer for this question

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php  if(!empty($r['category'])){ $cat = $r['category']; $cate=substr($cat,0,25) . '';
 //$cat = str_replace(' ', '', $cate);
  $cat = str_replace('&', '%26', $cat);  after changing it works fine // print_r($cat);?>
  <a href="enquiry.php?cat='<?php echo $cat  ;?>'">
```

`enter code here`