# Passing a url encoded string value

Tags: php, jquery, html

The urls are encoded using `urlencode()`.

www.myweb.com/pahe.html?artist=Taylor+Swift

I'm grabbing the string value to be able to pass via jquery's `$post()` to a php

```
$.post(my.php', 
     { word:"Taylor Swift" },
```

How can I pass a string as `Taylor Swift` instead of `Taylor+Swift`?

Comment: Use urldecode() function.

Comment: `+` is an encoded space in a URL parameter.

Comment: @VlastislavNovák thanks. can this be done in my html itself? Could you explain a bit more. :)

Comment: @Becky You can send encoded string (Taylor+Swift) with jquery and use urldecode() function in file my.php.

Comment: @VlastislavNovák  that explains it better. SO basically `urldecode()` removes all `+` in php. So I don't have to worry about the sting values in my html. right?

Comment: @VlastislavNovák is this a better solution? `utf8_decode(urldecode("") );`

Comment: @Bekky There's no need to use utf8_decode. You don't have to worry about it, if urldecode() function is used in PHP script.

Comment: @VlastislavNovák There seems to be a huge difference in the output between `urldecode("Ant%C3%B4nio+Carlos+Jobim");` and `utf8_decode(urldecode("Ant%C3%B4nio+Carlos+Jobim"))` according to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756862/url-decoding-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str_replace` to replace all `+` with spaces:

```
$artist = "Taylor+Swift";
echo urldecode($artist); // Taylor Swift
```

## JavaScript / HTML

If you don't have access to the server-side. You can do:

```
{ word: "Taylor+Swift".replace(/+/g, ' ') }
```

Comment: thanks. So `.replace(/+/g, ' ') ` replaces all `+` signs in the string?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
urldecode($url);
```

Comment: thanks. where could this go? in my html (where I grab the string parameters?)

Comment: But in my question I've said `I'm grabbing the string value to be able to pass via jquery's $post() to a php` ?