# How to remove escaping in PHP?

Tags: php, url, parameters, escaping

I have this URL parameter:

```
KKe%7bZoE_%24g)tjm%40
```

When I put it into a variable and echo it, the result is:

```
KKe{ZoE_$g)tjm@
```

How to avoid that?

Comment: How do you put that into a variable?

Comment: take a look into [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) and [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL Decoding in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756862/url-decoding-in-php)

Comment: OK, but when I use urlencode() the result is still different: **"KKe%7BZoE_%24g%29tjm%40"**

Comment: Be clear about what exactly you're doing, what you expect to happen and for what purpose. Your question is extremely vague and you will not get a useful answer with vague back and forth like this.

Comment: What I want to have is php variable, containing the exact URL as a string without any changes. This is verification code, that's why I use it. I want to send it again to check if the code is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data in `$_GET` is already URL-decoded. If you require the original string, get it from `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`. Note that you will have to process the query string yourself though, including breaking down the individual components.

Alternatively, use `rawurlencode($_GET[..])` to re-encode the value; which may or may not produce slightly differently encoded values than you originally got.

Answer (score 0):

Test it with [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/manual/de/function.html-entity-decode.php) - it helpt me a lot with my inputs.

Answer (score 0):

If the string is not shown as it is, you have **urlencode()** or **htmlentities()** somewhere in your code. Check that, you shouldn't encode html entities before echoing if you want the string to be intact.