# How to replace space to non breaking space?

Tags: php

I have parser which parsing urls.

In some parsed urls I have a simple space like **%20**, but if I check the real url of parsed site I see this non-breaking space **%C2%A0**.

So, how I can replace **%20** to **%C2%A0**?

```
foreach($productUrls as $href) {
   $productWithSpace = str_replace('%20', '%C2%A0', $href['url']);
   $link = 'http://optnow.ru/' . $productWithSpace;
   $product = file_get_html($link);
}
```

But It still not working.

Where is my mistake?

Thanks

Comment: How is `$href['url']` populated? `The superglobals $_GET and $_REQUEST are already decoded.`

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756862/url-decoding-in-php

Answer (score 0):

**What I believe you are asking for**

urlencode transforms spaces into '+'s, but if you want them to be %20, you can use rawurlencode to get around that.

```
$productWithSpace = rawurlencode(urldecode($href['url']));
$link = 'http://optnow.ru/' . $productWithSpace;
$product = file_get_html($link);
```

**I would use**

```
urldecode($string)
```

It will decode any urls automatically for you.  Less chance for user mistake.  Additionally, it decodes things you might not know needs to be decoded.

So, your new code would be (and this should fix your problem):

```
$productWithSpace = urldecode($href['url']);
$link = 'http://optnow.ru/' . $productWithSpace;
$product = file_get_html($link);
```