# Pass unencoded url from form

Tags: php, forms, url, decode

I've set up a search box on the homepage, that should link into the Opencart search by passing a URL.

The problem I'm having is that the resulting URL is always unencoded:

`store/index.php?route%3Dproduct%2Fsearch%26filter_name=test`

What I'm aiming for is

`store/index.php?route=product/search&filter_name=test`

My current code is:

```
<?php
$storesearch = $_REQUEST['store-search'] ;
$filter = 'route=product/search&filter_name';
$filtered = html_entity_decode($filter);
?>
<form id="store" method="GET" action="http://localhost/vinmobile/store/index.php?<?php echo $storesearch; ?>">
<input type="text" id="store-search" name="<?php echo $filtered; ?>" value="Store Search" onclick="this.value = '';">
<input type="submit" name="" value="Search">

</form>
<?php echo $filtered; ?> // Just to show it onscreen to make sure it's written correctly
```

I've tried encode, decode, html_entity_decode, urldecode, rawurldecode...
I've tried the form method as `GET, POST`
I've tried the variable declaration as `$_REQUEST, $_GET, $_POST`

Every time, I still end up with the url looking like:

`store/index.php?route%3Dproduct%2Fsearch%26filter_name=test`

I'm sure it's something simple I've missed, but I 'think' I've tried everything and would be very grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

Cheers

webecho

Comment: Have you tried doing a `utf8_decode` first?
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/1756925/6577664

Comment: I hadn't, but it still didn't work...
`$filter = 'route%3Dproduct%2Fsearch%26filter_name';

$filtered = utf8_decode(urldecode($filter));`

Also tried:
`$filter = 'route=product/search&filter_name';

$filtered = utf8_decode(urldecode($filter));`

Comment: What about adding the route to the form action?

i.e. `action=index.php?route=product/search` then give the your search field a name that stays consistent like `search`

Comment: Thanks Lucas
Yes, already tried that way (using filter_name) but the whole thing is re-written by opencart so it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using Javascript instead and it works perfectly:

```
`<script>
function process()
{
var url="store/index.php?route=product/search&filter_name=" + document.getElementById("filter").value;
location.href=url;
return false;
}
</script>
<form id="store" onSubmit="return process();">
<input type="text" name="filter" id="filter" value="Store Search" onclick="this.value = '';"> 
<input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>`
```

Thanks for your suggestions though